# Merge / and home partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted, merge

I used Linux 10 years ago for a couple of years and decided to use it again as my main OS this year. Initially, I installed Linux resizing my main Windows 10 partition. After a couple of weeks I decided to get more space from my Windows partition (`/dev/sda3`) to my Linux partition (`/dev/sda7`). That is when the problems started. My Linux partition did not recognize the free space within the partition, so I decided to reinstall the system. Currently, I do not know what happened, but System Monitor shows I have the root and home partitions separated as it shows on the images below:

[image]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

[image]

[image]

Comment: These look like LVM partitions.  Can you confirm these're LVM volumes?

Comment: Did you install Fedora? This is an Ubuntu forum. Fedora uses LVM by default, you have to choose separate partitions. And LVM really is best when it has entire drive. Ubuntu's default LVM erases everything and uses entire hard drive. If dual booting with Windows better to use separate standard partitions, not LVM, unless separate drive and you are experienced with Linux & using volumes instead of partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for your initial problem, where you expanded the partition, but it did not show up, you then needed to grow the filesystem as well. [Follow](https://serverfault.com/questions/509468/how-to-extend-an-ext4-partition-and-filesystem) this guide and your original issue would have been fixed.

Now coming to the actual question. Look carefully, you actually have both / and /home on the same partition (the lvm2pv partition).

**What is LVM?**

[LVM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-lvm-concepts-terminology-and-operations) is Logical Volume Management, it is a storage device management technology that gives users the power to pool and abstract the physical layout of component storage devices for easier and flexible administration.

**What the eff does it have to do with my problem?**

That is what I am getting at. You don't HAVE a problem. Yes, your / and /home might be in a different space, but they are on an LVM partition, and you can grow and shrink them as you need.

What's more, once you run out of space, just add another disk, add it to the LVM, and now you can see the space on that disk inside your /home. Learn how to manage LVM [here](https://www.tecmint.com/create-lvm-storage-in-linux/).

Yes, now with LVM, your /home can span over multiple physical volumes (partitions) on multiple disks (yes, your /home might also be on /dev/sdc4)

What you need to do is, learn up on LVM and enjoy your new found power and freedom. While others labour under the constrains of partitions and disk space, you can rise above it.

What's more, transitioning to another disk would also be easier. Just add the disk to your lvm, and then remove the current disk from the lvm, linux (and some other commands) will take care of everything else.*

- It is more complicated than that, but still doable.